# How to select latest Row from table without using ORDER BY

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, code-behind

How can I select latest row from by table without sorting it?

It is because it follow by the ID AUTO INCREMENT...

I'm using c# asp.net to select... I did try using LIMIT 5 but it give me an error page..

```
rSQL = "select COUNT(*) from chatLog_db where sessionid='" + grpID + "' LIMIT 5";
```

Is there any better way to solve this matter?

I'd appreciate any help please.

Comment: Please define 'latest row' and why you can't use ORDER BY

Comment: I only want to display latest 5 row from the sessionID which not auto increment

Comment: Dear see my updated answer and check second query,this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You have an id column which is autoincremented, right? Then you can do it like this..

```
select * from tablename where id=(select MAX(rid) from tablename)
```

Comment: but how to display only 5 or less?

Comment: try select * from tablename order by columnname desc LIMIT 5;

Comment: or SELECT TOP 10 * FROM custdetails1 ORDER BY customerid DESC

Comment: how do this if id is type guid

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
SELECT * FROM chatLog_db WHERE sessionid > (SELECT MAX(sessionid) - 1 FROM chatLog_db);
```

You may also try for

```
SELECT * FROM chatLog_db WHERE sessionid > (SELECT MAX(sessionid) - 5 FROM chatLog_db);
```

You may use `max` as well like

```
select * from chatLog_db where sessionid = (select max(sessionid) from chatLog_db);
```

Something like that.

If you are not using `order by` into your query because you are thinking that it will change the order of your dsplay data then i will tell you that there is one trick as well to `sort` your data as per your need

> you can also sort your data as per your need even if you are using
>   order by into your query,put the result into DataView and sort it
>   according to your need because DataView allow us sorting facility as
>   well.

Latest by using `Order By` like

```
select * from tablename order by columnname desc LIMIT 5;
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: but how to display only 5 or less?

Comment: it's very confusing that in your question you are mentioning that `How to select latest Row from table without using ORDER BY` and now you want `to display only 5 or less`...

Comment: because i want to read it from the latest...if i were to sort it out,my display would not in order..i just want to display 5 latest record...sorry for the inconvinience

Comment: if you want to display the data then why you are using `count(*)` into your query.It just give you `integer` value but not `data`

Comment: you can also sort your data as per your need even if you are using `order by` into your query,put the result into `DataView` and sort it according to your need because `DataView` allow us sorting facility as well.

Comment: i tried using "select * from table where sessionid ='"+grpID+"' limit 5"; but still can't use limit for it..because i only want to display 5 at my asp:textbox

Comment: this query will run but it will give you `first 5` rows not `last 5` rows.

Comment: then how to get last 5 row?

Answer (score 0):

if the latest means the max id

```
   select * from chatLog_db 
   where id = (select max(id) from chatLog_db);
```

**EDIT**

select 5 records

```
   select * from chatLog_db 
   where id > (select max(id) - 5 from chatLog_db);
```

Comment: but how to display only 5 or less?

Answer (score 0):

On MSSQL simply use the `top 1` instead of limit

```
select top(1) * from mytable order by some_column
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx